# Installing railway cli after running npm i -g @railway/cli i get errors

Tags: nvm

Iam trying to install railway cli

```
npm i -g @railway/cli
/home/isaac/.nvm/versions/node/v14.10.0/bin/railway -> /home/isaac/.nvm/versions/node/v14.10.0/lib/node_modules/@railway/cli/bin/railway.js

> @railway/cli@2.0.13 postinstall /home/isaac/.nvm/versions/node/v14.10.0/lib/node_modules/@railway/cli
> node ./npm-install/postinstall.js

internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'stream' imported from /home/isaac/.nvm/versions/node/v14.10.0/lib/node_modules/@railway/cli/npm-install/postinstall.js
    at packageResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:624:9)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:665:18)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:779:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:85:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:229:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:51:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:50:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @railway/cli@2.0.13: wanted: {"node":">=16.0.0"} (current: {"node":"14.10.0","npm":"6.14.8"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @railway/cli@2.0.13
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for node-fetch@3.3.0: wanted: {"node":"^12.20.0 || ^14.13.1 || >=16.0.0"} (current: {"node":"14.10.0","npm":"6.14.8"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: node-fetch@3.3.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for fetch-blob@3.2.0: wanted: {"node":"^12.20 || >= 14.13"} (current: {"node":"14.10.0","npm":"6.14.8"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: fetch-blob@3.2.0

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @railway/cli@2.0.13 postinstall: `node ./npm-install/postinstall.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @railway/cli@2.0.13 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/isaac/.npm/_logs/2022-12-06T07_16_56_179Z-debug.log
```

I get this error, i have tried everything but i cannot proceed

I have downgraded my node versions but still getting the same errors

Answer (score 0):

Please update your node version to latest one. Refer this solution for same: https://askubuntu.com/a/480642. Then run `hash -r` to reset the location hash for bash.

Then simply run `sudo npm i -g @railway/cli`.